# Applying matrix functions like scipy.linalg.eigh to higher dimensional arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I am new to numpy but have been using python for quite a while as an engineer.
I am writing a program that currently stores stress tensors as 3x3 numpy arrays within another NxM array which represents values through time and through the thickness of a wall, so overall it is an NxMx3x3 numpy array.  I want to efficiently calculate the eigenvals and vectors of each 3x3 array within this larger array. So far I have tried to using "fromiter" but this doesn't seem to work because the functions returns 2 arrays.  I have also tried apply_along_axis which also doesn't work because it says the inner 3x3 is not a square matrix? I can do it with list comprehension, but this doesn't seem ideal to resort to using lists.

Example just calculating eigenvals using list comprehension

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg
a=np.random.random((2,2,3,3))
f=linalg.eigvalsh
ans=np.asarray([f(x) for x in a.reshape((4,3,3))])
ans.shape=(2,2,3)
```

I thought something like this would work but I have played around with it and can't get it working:

```
np.apply_along_axis(f,0,a)
```

BTW the 2x2 bit could be up to 5000x100 and this code is repeated ~50x50x200 times hence the need for efficiency. Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: Does the list comprehension work? You won't  get anything faster or simpler,

Comment: It does work, I was just thinking there would be a more numpyish way of doing it that kept it all as numpy arrays. But if not I will just live with it.

Comment: Functions like `apply_along_axis` are convenience functions.  They make certain actions easier, but not faster.  You might make it work by reshaping the array to (N,M,9), and wrapping `eigvalsh` in a function that reshapes the (9,) input to (3,3).  But `eigvalsh` is still called once for each of N*M arrays.

Comment: Are the (3,3)s symmetric?  They aren't in your example.  What does the function require?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.linalg.eigh`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigh.html). It accepts an array like your example `a`.

Here's an example.  First, create an array of 3x3 symmetric arrays:

```
In [96]: a = np.random.random((2, 2, 3, 3))

In [97]: a = a + np.transpose(a, axes=(0, 1, 3, 2))

In [98]: a[0, 0]
Out[98]: 
array([[0.61145048, 0.85209618, 0.03909677],
       [0.85209618, 1.79309413, 1.61209077],
       [0.03909677, 1.61209077, 1.55432465]])
```

Compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of all the 3x3 arrays:

```
In [99]: evals, evecs = np.linalg.eigh(a)

In [100]: evals.shape
Out[100]: (2, 2, 3)

In [101]: evecs.shape
Out[101]: (2, 2, 3, 3)
```

Take a look at the result for `a[0, 0]`:

```
In [102]: evals[0, 0]
Out[102]: array([-0.31729364,  0.83148477,  3.44467813])

In [103]: evecs[0, 0]
Out[103]: 
array([[-0.55911658,  0.79634401,  0.23070516],
       [ 0.63392772,  0.23128064,  0.73800062],
       [-0.53434473, -0.55887877,  0.63413738]])
```

Verify that it is the same as computing the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for `a[0, 0]` separately:

```
In [104]: np.linalg.eigh(a[0, 0])
Out[104]: 
(array([-0.31729364,  0.83148477,  3.44467813]),
 array([[-0.55911658,  0.79634401,  0.23070516],
        [ 0.63392772,  0.23128064,  0.73800062],
        [-0.53434473, -0.55887877,  0.63413738]]))
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I tried first and got this error: >>> n,m=linalg.eigh(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/decomp.py", line 376, in eigh
    raise ValueError('expected square matrix')
ValueError: expected square matrix  - I have just restarted my python interpreter and this works now.  I am very confused.  Sorry for wasting your time and thank you very much.

Comment: It looks like you used `scipy.linalg.eigh` in your first attempt.  `scipy` and `numpy` each have there own `linalg` subpackage, and the functions in them are not exactly the same.  In this case, `numpy.linalg.eigh` handles the higher dimensional array, but `scipy.linalg.eigh` does not.

Comment: *"Sorry for wasting your time..."* No need to apologize!  You are not the first, and won't be the last, to be confused by the overlap (and the discrepancies therein) between numpy and scipy.